# JOOQ sbt 0.3.16 to 1.2.8 migration

Tags: sbt, jooq

How migrate JOOQ building and configuration from sbt 0.3.16 to sbt 1.2.8

The JOOQ build definition in 0.3.16 as below.

```
val generateJOOQ = taskKey[Seq[File]]("Generate JooQ classes")

val generateJOOQTask = (baseDirectory, dependencyClasspath in Compile, runner in Compile, streams) map { (base, cp, r, s) =>
  toError (r.run(
    "org.jooq.util.GenerationTool",
    cp.files,
    Array("conf/openDoor.xml"),
    s.log))
  ((base / "app" / "jooqSteps") ** "*.scala").get
}

generateJOOQ <<= generateJOOQTask
```

and the result when running sbt (1.2.8):

```
build.sbt:70: error: value map is not a member of (sbt.SettingKey[java.io.File], sbt.TaskKey[sbt.Keys.Classpath], sbt.TaskKey[sbt.ScalaRun], sbt.TaskKey[sbt.Keys
.TaskStreams])
val generateJOOQTask = (baseDirectory, dependencyClasspath in Compile, runner in Compile, streams) map { (base, cp, r, s) =>
                                                                                                   ^
C:\workPlay\anchor\build.sbt:71: error: not found: value toError
  toError (r.run(
  ^
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [migrating from tuple enrichments](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-013x.html#Migrating+from+the+tuple+enrichments) guide and [dropped deprecations release notes](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/sbt-1.0-Release-Notes.html#sbt+1.0.0) we could migrate `generateJOOQTask` as follows

```
val generateJOOQ = taskKey[Seq[File]]("Generate JooQ classes")
generateJOOQ := {
  val base = baseDirectory.value
  val cp = (dependencyClasspath in Compile).value
  val r = (runner in Compile).value
  val s = streams.value

  r.run(
    "org.jooq.util.GenerationTool",
    cp.files,
    Array("conf/openDoor.xml"),
    s.log
  ).failed foreach (sys error _.getMessage)

  ((base / "app" / "jooqSteps") ** "*.scala").get

}
```