# Errors while upgrading Play/Scala/SBT/jOOQ/HSQLDB application

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, hsqldb, jooq

I am trying to upgrade the dependencies of a play/scala/sbt/jooq/hsqdb project.
But I am getting the following errors when I try to generate classes by jOOQ from HSQLDB tables.

**build.sbt**

```
name := "CH07"

version := "1.0"

lazy val `ch07` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.13.4"

resolvers += "Spy Repository" at "http://files.couchbase.com/maven2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  "com.github.mumoshu" %% "play2-memcached-play24" % "0.7.0",
  "org.hsqldb" % "hsqldb" % "2.5.0",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq" % "3.14.4",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq-codegen-maven" % "3.14.4",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq-meta" % "3.14.4",
  "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.7",
  "com.github.ironfish" %% "akka-persistence-mongo-casbah"  % "0.7.6"
)

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

val generateJOOQ = taskKey[Seq[File]]("Generate JooQ classes")

val generateJOOQTask = (baseDirectory, dependencyClasspath in Compile, runner in Compile, streams) map { (base, cp, r, s) =>
  toError(r.run(
    "org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool",
    cp.files,
    Array("conf/chapter7.xml"),
    s.log))
  ((base / "app" / "generated") ** "*.scala").get
}

generateJOOQ <<= generateJOOQTask

libraryDependencies += "com.ning" % "async-http-client" % "1.9.29"
```

**project/plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.6")
//addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.10")

//used to work with jooq 3.7.1
//addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.3")
```

**project/build.properties**

```
sbt.version=1.4.4
```

**I try to generate classes with jOOQ, but I am getting errors** (but it used to work before I upgraded the dependencies):

**With `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.6")`**

```
$ sbt -java-home /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.1 generateJOOQ
[info] welcome to sbt 1.4.4 (Oracle Corporation Java 11.0.1)
[info] loading settings for project ch07-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from /home/myname/projects/textbook/CH07/project
/home/myname/projects/textbook/CH07/build.sbt:48: error: value map is not a member of (sbt.SettingKey[java.io.File], sbt.TaskKey[sbt.Keys.Classpath], sbt.TaskKey[sbt.ScalaRun], sbt.TaskKey[sbt.Keys.TaskStreams])
val generateJOOQTask = (baseDirectory, dependencyClasspath in Compile, runner in Compile, streams) map { (base, cp, r, s) =>
                                                                                                   ^
/home/myname/projects/textbook/CH07/build.sbt:49: error: not found: value toError
  toError(r.run(
  ^
sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
[warn] Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? (default: r)
```

So with Play sbt-plugin 2.8.6, how should I rewrite the code for `generateJOOQTask`?
(also, I don't understand why the Play sbt-plugin would be relevant to the jOOQ code?)

**With `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.10")`**

```
$ sbt -java-home /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.1 generateJOOQ
[info] welcome to sbt 1.4.4 (Oracle Corporation Java 11.0.1)
[info] loading settings for project ch07-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from /home/myname/projects/textbook/CH07/project
[info] Updating 
[info] Resolved  dependencies
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.5.10 (sbtVersion=1.0, scalaVersion=2.12)
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:2.5.10
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.12_1.0/2.5.10/sbt-plugin-2.5.10.pom
[error]   not found: /home/myname/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.5.10/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.5.10/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.5.10/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.unresolvedWarningOrThrow(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:258)
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.$anonfun$update$38(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:227)
[error]     at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:573)
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.update(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:227)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:60)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:53)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:103)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:73)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$20(LibraryManagement.scala:116)
[error]     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:228)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:116)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:97)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChangedW$1(Tracked.scala:219)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:130)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask0$5(Defaults.scala:3485)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:282)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:291)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:282)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:64)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:2.5.10
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.12_1.0/2.5.10/sbt-plugin-2.5.10.pom
[error]   not found: /home/myname/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.5.10/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.5.10/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.5.10/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? (default: r)
```

So with Play sbt-plugin 2.5.10, it seems like at this point sbt tries to download a non-existing `com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin`.

How do I know what the correct version is and how to tell sbt how to find it? (shouldn't what I wrote in `build.sbt` be enough for an intelligent system to understand what to do?)

Comment: Are you sure those are the only changes to your build since it was working? Your first error seems to be related to features that were dropped from sbt when they went from 0.13 to 1.0

Comment: The problem is that Play 2.8 is only published for sbt 1.x, whereas Play 2.5 is not. Both errors originate from this incompatibility -- you cannot use Play 2.5 with sbt 1.x (it does not exist -> not found), you cannot use old build definitions with sbt 1.x.

Comment: I have made some more changes due to renaming of class packages, which solved the exceptions — until I hit this one (with Play sbt-plugin 2.8.6). Any idea how to rewrite the `generateJOOQTask`? My understanding of sbt is shallow, so I try to do some reading. The sbt syntax/internals are not intuitive.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55693890/jooq-sbt-0-3-16-to-1-2-8-migration, I'm going to flag this a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JOOQ sbt 0.3.16 to 1.2.8 migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55693890/jooq-sbt-0-3-16-to-1-2-8-migration)

Comment: @CharlieFlowers Not fully, it still does not work. See below the answer by cbley. Also, there is more info in cbley answer. As opposed to the answer you linked to, which is styled more as a recipe.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
val generateJOOQTask = (baseDirectory, dependencyClasspath in Compile, runner in Compile, streams) map { (base, cp, r, s) =>
  ...
}
```

is old sbt 0.13 syntax. Replace with:

```
generateJOOQ := {
  val base = baseDirectory.value
  val cp = dependencyClasspath.in(Compile).value
  val r = runner.in(Compile).value
  val s = streams.value

  ...
}
```

The `toError` method was dropped in sbt 1.x, replace it with

```
r.run(...).failed foreach (sys error _.getMessage)
```

Then, this:

```
generateJOOQ <<= generateJOOQTask
```

is deprecated sbt 0.12 syntax. Replace it with

```
generateJOOQ := generateJOOQTask.value
```

(note, I combined this with the val above)

Comment: error: `value` can only be used within a task or setting macro, such as :=, +=, ++=, Def.task, or Def.setting. — val base = baseDirectory.value — also: r.run(
    "org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool",
    cp.files,
    Array("conf/chapter7.xml"),
    s.log)
    .failed foreach (sys error _.getMessage)

  ((base / "app" / "generated") ** "*.scala").get — it says: cannot resolve symbol failed

Comment: Right, need to combine this with the first setting.

Comment: I think you can either do it as `val generateJOOQTask = ...` and then `generateJOOQ := generateJOOQTask.value`, OR simply `generateJOOQ := {...}`. Either way, I am getting compilation error on "failed", "foreach", "getMessage". Error message (in Intellij) is "cannot resolve symbol failed". Is it due to sbt version? In `project/build.properties` I have `sbt.version=1.4.4` — Is this what determines the sbt version used for compilation in Intellij?

Comment: No, since the `.value` macro is only available for tasks and settings, not when defining a simple val.

Comment: That solved the `.value` error, but I still get the compilation error inside Intellij: compilation error on "failed", "foreach", "getMessage". Error message (in Intellij) is "cannot resolve symbol failed". The code I am using in build.sbt can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55697023/784980

Comment: `failed` is a method on `scala.util.Try` which exists regardless which sbt version you use. Maybe IntelliJ is confused for some other reason... does it work when you use sbt directly?

Comment: I don't know yet, there is another dependency that is not clear to me how to upgrade. I cannot easily mute it, because it's used in multiple places.